# why was the java.util.Date and java.sql.Date getSeconds, getMinutes, getHours, getDays, setDays, setMonths and so on methods depricated?

Tags: java, date, time

I'm creating an application in which storing dates and times is important and I find myself using four different classes to store date and time in various parts of my application. The java.util.Date class is terrible, it lacks the functionality I would expec. I found the joda-DateTime class which is nice but of course jSpinner doesn't support it properly so I find myself casting to java.sql.Time and the like.
Then there was the issue of finding a nice DateTime selector with a calendar for date and a time selector. I ended up using a third party Date selector and a jSpinner for time selector. It just seems to me that java is somewhat lacking for DateTime.

Comment: Have a look at the new Java 8 Date and Time API (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)

Answer (score 0):

They were replaced with the Calendar class. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html.